# read.csv imports half of observations from source file in R

Tags: r, csv, import

When I try te `read.csv()` a file of 10.513 rows with R I only get 5.458 observations. I loose whole months of data, October for example, while there **is** October data in the original csv. What goes wrong I wonder...

```
library(tidyverse)

original_df <- read.csv("2017-12-11_tweets.csv")
tweets_2015_now <- as.tibble(original_df)
tweets_2015_now

A tibble: 5,458 x 7
               source
               <fctr>
 1 Twitter for iPhone
 2 Twitter for iPhone
 3 Twitter for iPhone
 4       Media Studio
 5 Twitter for iPhone
 6 Twitter for iPhone
 7 Twitter for iPhone
 8 Twitter for iPhone
 9 Twitter for iPhone
10 Twitter for iPhone
# ... with 5,448 more rows, and 6 more variables: text <fctr>, created_at <fctr>, retweet_count <int>,
#   favorite_count <int>, is_retweet <fctr>, id_str <dbl>
```

Original file (`2017-12-11_tweets.csv`):
[image: Original file has 10.513 rows]
And I can find October in the original file but not when it's imported:
[image: October is definately there]

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings? Do you get the same results if you try using, say,  `data.table::fread` or `readr::read_csv`? If you get 5.458 rows, what does row 5.459 look like in your file?

Comment: Do you get any warning when your code executes?

Comment: initially I didn't get warnings but with `reader::read_csv` I got 6.151 observations but 2127 parsing failures I see now. I now decided to go for `~sprintf(url, .x)` a json directly from the webpage that seems to work.

Comment: My guess would be a mix of # and quote marks messing things up. Maybe try `read.csv("myfile.csv", quote = "", comment = "")`

Comment: Wow that worked! thanks @richardjtelford!